# Git Remote Repository Merge

Tags: git

I am a bit new to Git and am trying to figure why this isn't working.

I've created my own git "origin" server "git@myserver.com". I've cloned over a bare repo from another git server "git@theirserver.com". I cloned a working copy from git@myserver.com to my local machine. I wanted to use one of the branches as our master, so I branched off from "sample_branch", made a few changes, and pushed it to our origin master.

Now, I'm going to need to periodically fetch the updated code from git@theirserver.com and merge it into my origin master. On my local machine, I clone a fresh copy of the repo from the origin server and create a "update" branch off of master. I then:

```
 $git remote add them ssh://git@theirserver.com/app/

 $git fetch them sample_branch

 $git merge FETCH_HEAD

 Already up-to-date.
```

Why is this telling me the branch is already up to date? If I look at the README file within my "update" branch, it has the changes I made to it. If I checkout the remote "them/sample_branch" branch, it does not have the changes. Why is it not recognizing the differences between these files?

Answer (score 0):

It is up to date with your local version, use origin to pull or merge to get the remote version of the branch/repo.

Comment: You're saying when I'm merging, it's checking that "them/sample_branch" is up to date with the branch on git@theirserver.com? Could you give me example commands on how I would merge that remote branch into mine?

Comment: git pull origin branch_name or git merge origin branch_name

Comment: or pull the remote origin to your local version of it and then pull the local into the branch you want to merge it into

Comment: If I "git pull origin sample_branch", it just says it's up to date, which is expected. I tried specifying the merge "git merge update:them/sample_branch" and I get "not something we can merge"